# Logo Sub Category Name or Logo Sub Brand Design

Tags: logo, design-principles, terminology

I'm looking for the **technical term** if there is one of when brands have a sub category or sub brand and they alter their **logo** slightly. I'm looking for some inspiration of this online of how it's done.

Virgin provides on example of this:

[image: Virgin logos]

Some other example of what I mean: , [Asos Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuWpM.jpg), [Violeta by Mango](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w10A.jpg), [Vera Wang Princess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDozR.jpg), [Love](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JY6J.jpg)

So what do you call this when a brand does this to their logo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call this a "range" of their main brand or "subsidiary brands". So Virgin's Active range or Vera Wang's Love range.

Comment: I'll second "subsidiary."

Comment: Thanks! Subsidiary & Range seems to be the words thrown around the most, but its very hard to find a website with examples of JUST subsidiary logos...

Answer (score 4):

**Collateral Branding** is often the term used for items used that have a similar, but different, brand for the same company.

Collateral Marketing means items being used to sell.. ads, flyers, brochures, etc.

Collateral materials means identity items, cards, letterhead, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Subsidiary seems to work if you talk about companies. extracted from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsidiary):

> A subsidiary, subsidiary company, or daughter company is a
>   company that is owned or controlled by another company, which is
>   called the parent company, parent, or holding company.

But I'd say Range is more common for brands. Example: [Amazon 'to launch range of own-brand food'](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/newsbysector/retailandconsumer/11637488/Amazon-to-launch-range-of-own-brand-food.html)

Comment: SaturnsEye said this first but thanks for your detailed explanation... +1

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know is Brand Architecture. There are potentially 3 types of brand architectures which is nothing but a framework into which its brands fall.
Your question has more than one brand architecture.

Virgin brand follows "Corporate or Monolithic" Brand Identity where its sub brands share the same first name. Subsidiary is a very generic term to define any brands under a parent company. I would perhaps call it a legal term.

Your other example is Violetta by Mango is a classic example of "Endorsed" Brand Identity. It can either be endorsed by a group name or visual style (Ex. IKEA and LIDL)

The last type in this architecture is "Branded" brand based identity. This happens when companies separate their identities as corporations from those of the brands which they market. Example Unilever which owns Dove, Ponds, etc; all of which have separate brand identities.

Now, coming back to your question. What do you call this when a brand does to its logo?
You can call these brands as sub brands or brand extensions.

Source: Wally Olins 2008
http://www.thamesandhudson.com/Wally_Olins_The_Brand_Handbook/9780500514085

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is called Brand Nomenclature.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.